# How to test iOS Core Bluetooth project in Macbook?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, bluetooth

I want to learn CB (Core Bluetooth) framework in iOS. Any practical example or links from where I could understand this deeply?

Comment: you must use real iOS device

Answer (score 0):

Basic BLE swift lang tutorial for beginners :

http://www.kevinhoyt.com/2016/05/20/the-12-steps-of-bluetooth-swift/

follows above link, it's best link for learn core bluetooth with swift lang.

Must be require iOS device which supported Bluetooth 4.0 and later version. BLE not supported in simulator(Xcode).